# object is not destroyed after catching exception in mixed C and C++ code programming

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

I am writing a program using mixing c and c++, and I meet a problem about object destruction in c++ exception handler. I wrote a simple case to reproduce the problem.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void test(void(*f)(void));

struct foo {
    ~foo() {
        std::cout << "foo destruction" << std::endl;
    }
};

void error_handler(void) {
    throw 1;
}

int main() {
    try {
        foo f;
        test(error_handler);
    } catch (...) {

    }
}
```

**test.c**

```
void test(void(*handler)(void)) {
    handler();
}
```

When I build this in Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017, the `foo`'s destructor was not called. But when I test it using gcc 5.4, the `foo`'s destructor works fine.

Is it possible to throw C++ exception in C code through calling function pointer (which pointer to the function implemented in cpp code)? Is the code above illegal or it's just an msvc bug?

Comment: The answer in simple words: No.

Comment: The problem is that visual studio doesn´t stop the programm at the end. If you use Code Blocks u see the output of the destructor.

Comment: This would require the exception thrown to pass through the C code and back to C++. Surely the C standard says nothing about this.

Comment: @Matthias It is not the reason. Break point is also not be hitted.

Comment: Compile with `/EHa`.

Comment: You cannot mix C and C++ source code! `extern "C"` only specified the C ABI, not the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows Exception mechanism is explicitly designed to be able to run destructors and perform finally type cleanup even in the presence of exceptions and similar from other languages.

So what you're asking should work fine on windows - its what its designed to do.

However, you need to explicitly enable this in Visual Studio. By default, visual studio sets up C++ code with `/EHsc` exception model which explicitly assume that `extern "C"` functions *do not throw or pass through exceptions*. This is an optimisation, and generally a good one.

However, if you need to assume that `extern "C"` functions do throw or pass through exceptions then you need to change your exception model. You probably want `/EHs`.

However, I'd recommend reading up on the ramifications of this before you change it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model).

Edit: Whether to use this functionality or not is debatable. Generally with exceptions (and other similar mechanisms) all code on the stack between the thrower and caller need to be exception safe. If you own the code then this is fine, if there's things like windows callbacks or other libraries on the stack then you need to find a guarantee that this is ok. And in general for [windows internal code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120910-00/?p=6653) its not.

Answer (score 3):

Throwing exceptions across language boundaries always leaves program in inconsistent state. Stack unwinding performed in case of C++ exception thrown is guaranteed to work only on (binary compatible) C++ stack frames. C language does not even have a concept of exceptions. Even if stack unwinding manages to unwind C stack frames it will not perform any cleanup for them. So any callback function passed to C code should be declared as `noexcept` and handle error in some manner that does not involve throwing of exception across language boundary:

```
void error_handler(void) noexcept {
   try
   {
      throw 1;
   } 
   catch(…)
   {
       // TODO convert to error code or store for later using exception_ptr
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I got the problem when I was using libharu. I followed the documentation to implement Error handling, here is the ducument https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/Error-handling#the-typical-usage-of-error-handler-with-c-1

Comment: @benlypan I'm not familiar with that library, however if `HPDF_New` is a C function then that example code is definitely not good. You may want to send a new issue for devs.